# simplify find command with 0 or 1 time repeat pattern

Tags: bash, find

How can I simplify below find command with pattern:

```
find . -type d -name symbols -o -name symbol
```

The pattern is 'symbol' + 0 or 1 's'.

Comment: unfortunately standard `find` can't do that so you need to specify the target OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `-regex`, but it must match the whole path, so you need to prepend `.*/` to match the path.

```
find . -type d -regex '.*/symbols?'
```

Comment: Awesome, is -regex support by all linux system?

Comment: Not part of POSIX, so I guess it's not supported everywhere (e.g. openbsd etc.)